# Convert web site to a web application project

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Hallo,
I converted a web site to a web application project (visual Studio 2005) but now files doesn't find my classes (.vb)! 
Into the web site are classes automatically into App_code folder. 
After conversion don't exist App_code folder but only Old_App_Code folder.
I tried to copy my old .vb classes into the root folder but without results.
I don't understand how to connect files with classes.
Any ideas?
Thank's, Ptricia.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check [these](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx) two [guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(VS.80).aspx) out